# Importance of an extra total derivative term in Liouville theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0610197) paper on boundary Liouville theory, the authors have introduced an extra term, $-\partial_{\sigma}^2\phi$, (the last term in the equation below) in defining the stress tensor of the Liouville theory as,
\begin{align}
\mathcal E = T+\bar T = \frac12\left(\partial_\tau\phi\right)^2+\frac12\left(\partial_\sigma\phi\right)^2+2m^2e^{2\phi}-\partial_{\sigma}^2\phi. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Moreoever, in writing the action for the theory this means that this extra term also appears in the action,
\begin{equation}
S=\int\limits_M\!d^2x \left[ \frac12\left(\partial_\tau\phi\right)^2-\frac12\left(\partial_\sigma\phi\right)^2-2m^2e^{2\phi}+\partial_\sigma^2\phi\right].\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Here it is just a total derivative boundary term. In particular, if the boundary is at $\sigma=0,\pi$ (as is the case in the paper), then the boundary term is $$-\int \!d\tau\left(\frac12\phi\partial_\sigma\phi-\partial_\sigma\phi\right).\tag{3}$$
Under the variation of the field $\phi$,
\begin{equation}
\delta\phi \,\partial_\sigma\phi = \partial_\sigma\delta\phi.\tag{4}
\end{equation}
on the boundary, requiring one to impose both Dirichlet, $\delta\phi = 0$ as well as Neumann boundary condition, $\partial_\sigma\delta\phi=0$ simultaneously. In the paper, the authors are studying Dirichlet problem. This looks weird and unfamiliar to me. In the standard scalar field theory where you don't have any term like $\partial_\sigma^2\phi$ the boundary variation is simply, $-\delta\phi \,\partial_\sigma\phi =0$, which is zero under Dirichlet boundary conditions.

So why is this extra term required in the Liouville theory?